# Creating new GeoServer user through rest api?

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api, geoserver-geofence

I've tried posting this xml:

```xml
<user>
    <userName>Jim</userName>
    <password>password</password>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
</user>
```

to these addresses:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/usergroup/user
404 - "Not Found"
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/usergroup/users/user
404 - "Not Found"
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/security/usergroup/user
404 - "Not Found"
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/security/usergroup/users/
500 - "Server Error"
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/security/usergroup/users/user
404 - "Not Found"
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/security/usergroup/user/Jim
500 - "Server Error"
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/security/usergroup/users/Jim
404 - "Not Found"
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/security/usergroup/users/user/Jim
404 - "Not Found"
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/security/usergroup/service/MyGroup/user
404 - "Not Found"
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/security/usergroup/service/MyGroup/users
500 - "Server Error"
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/security/usergroup/service/MyGroup/users/user
404 - "Not Found"
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/security/usergroup/service/MyGroup/user/Jim
500 - "Server Error"
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/security/usergroup/service/MyGroup/users/Jim
404 - "Not Found"
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/security/usergroup/service/MyGroup/users/user/Jim
404 - "Not Found"
```

I've tried with and without the **GeoFence plugin**.

Is this actually possible?

I have succeeded in creating roles, usergroups, workspaces, coverageStores and raster layers from GeoTiff files, and dataStores and vector layers from shapefiles, but no progress on creating users.

I gather that some modules require you to change the admin password from the default, so I've done that too.  My admin account has `ADMIN`, `GROUP_ADMIN`, and `ROLE_ADMIN` roles, and I've even added a `USER_ADMIN` role in the case such a thing exists.

***I'm running geoserver-2.12-SNAPSHOT from 18 September.***

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who's still getting problems with this, it's been fixed in v2.15.1. I've updated it and it all works no problems now, although I'm using the `rest/security/usergroup/users/` route as I get a 404 if I try `rest/usergroups/users`

https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=10000&version=16753

Answer (score 2):

I have found temporary solution for this.

The reason of this is that the XStream cannot map XML/JSON to org.geoserver.rest.security.xml.JaxbUser because there is no alias "user" for this.

There are two solutions for it.

1. Use full class name with package in your XML/JSON.

Something like this:

```
{
"org.geoserver.rest.security.xml.JaxbUser":{

  "userName": "test",
  "password": "test",
  "enabled": true
}
}
```

If you use XML there is propably the same way.

2. Edit org.geoserver.rest.security.UsersRestController class.

Add super class org.geoserver.rest.RestBaseController to it and override two methods

```
@Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter methodParameter, Type targetType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
        return JaxbUser.class.isAssignableFrom(methodParameter.getParameterType());
    }

    @Override
    public void configurePersister(XStreamPersister persister, XStreamMessageConverter converter) {
           persister.setHideFeatureTypeAttributes();

            persister.getXStream().alias("user", JaxbUser.class);
    }
```

After one of those solutions you need to add JaxbUser.class to XStream whitelist. The simplest way to do it is adding system/environment/context variable GEOSERVER_XSTREAM_WHITELIST like GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR.
E.g -DGEOSERVER_XSTREAM_WHITELIST=org.geoserver.rest.security.xml.JaxbUser

I hope this will be fixed in next versions of Geoserver. By the way the GeoServer Documentation is full of lack and need to be polished.

I have [posted](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-8486) the same on Jira.

Answer (score 1):

You are very close. The [documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/community/geofence-server/rest-userrole.html#requests) shows that you need to POST to

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/usergroup/service/users/
```

As long as you are executing the POST as a user with the role ROLE_ADMIN it should work as expected.

Comment: `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/usergroup/service/users/

404 - "Not Found"

http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/security/usergroup/service/users/

404 - "Not Found"`

I'm afraid the documentation has shown lots of examples that are incorrect.
Sorry - I can't get sensible formatting in this comment.

Comment: The documentation shows the url as `/rest/usergroup/[service/<serviceName>/]users/` so if I include the "service" element in the path then that needs to be followed by a service name e.g. "default" or "MyGroup".
I should be able to list users at this url but actually I need to include the "security" element in the path to get it to work.

Comment: please submit a PR for the docs if you find an issue

Comment: Any news on this? I'm experiencing the same issue with the 2.12.0 version of GeoServer. The docs seems to be wrong, one has to add the /security/ to the url to access the usergroup rest api as mentioned above. The POST to the same url does not work, I get a 500 error. Besides the docs says that I should be able to perform all requests with content-type and accept header application/json but this gives a 406 Not acceptable error.

Comment: I am getting similar results, bot xml and json posts are reporting 500 errors for me on GeoServer 2.12.1. Checking the logs I get: Testing /rest/security/usergroup/users/ for monitor filtering
ERROR [geoserver.rest] - user
com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException

Comment: I have same problem, always gives 404 - "Not Found" and I can't find ROLE_ADMIN configuration for using rest api. How can I do it.

Comment: i found and issue ticket created here: https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-8486

Answer (score 0):

我使用的Json方式，需要在参数外面包一层 user
{
"user": {
"userName": "test",
"password": "123456",
"enabled": true
}
}
[image]

Translation note: The above text translates to "The Json method I use needs to wrap a layer outside the parameters" ...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Added a translation. @yl-l where possible, it might be advised to add english translation. (Even if the text isn't high quality, English speakers will likely be able to fix it for you later on.).