# Adding new ROLES and USERS through REST in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver-rest-api

I use GeoServer stable version 2.14.1 and get error messages when trying to add new roles and users via REST.

I suspect that the GeoServer REST documentation is buggy. When I call the REST interface of my GeoServer instance, I can see that the roles are accessible through the URI `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/security/roles`. Users are under the URI `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/security/usergroup/users`.

I can query both resources via GET request, but adding new resources via POST or PUT will not work. A POST request to create new roles ends up with status code 405 (Method not allowed). After trying to create new users comes the status code 500 (Internal Server Error).

For this, the GeoServer-REST documentation has been referencing the paths

> /roles/roles/{role}

for new roles ([API-Doc](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/api/#/latest/en/api/1.0.0/roles.yaml)) or

> /usergroup/users/

for new users ([API-Doc](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/api/#/latest/en/api/1.0.0/usergroup.yaml)) since several GeoServer versions. But when I use them, this always ends with Status code 404 (Not Found).

How can I add new roles and users through REST in GeoServer?

The workarround from @implssv in [Creating new GeoServer user through rest api?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/256891) does not work for me.

Comment: please add the messages that you are PUTing to the server and any error messages that are generated by the server (look in the log file)