# GeoServer /role endpoint not working

Tags: geoserver-rest-api

I have been successful in using the GeoServer API to create workspaces and data sources, but I believe the documentation is quite buggy, since I cannot use the "roles" endpoint, for reference: https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/api/#/latest/en/api/1.0.0/roles.yaml

I looked at:
[How can I add new ROLES and USERS through REST in GeoServer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/309008/how-can-i-add-new-roles-and-users-through-rest-in-geoserver) so it appears I'm not the only one with this issue.

When I call either GET to /roles or /security/roles I simply get:

```
statusCode: 200

<html>
<head>
<title> Geoserver Configuration API </title>
<meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW"/>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Geoserver Configuration API</h2>
<ul>
<li><a href="host:8080/geoserver/rest/security/roles/workspaces">workspaces</a></li>
<li><a href="host:8080/geoserver/rest/security/roles/namespaces">namespaces</a></li>
<li><a href="host:8080/geoserver/rest/security/roles/styles">styles</a></li>
<li><a href="host:8080/geoserver/rest/security/roles/layers">layers</a></li>
<li><a href="host:8080/geoserver/rest/security/roles/layergroups">layergroups</a></li>
<li><a href="host:8080/geoserver/rest/security/roles/reload">reload</a></li>
<li><a href="host:8080/geoserver/rest/security/roles/reset">reset</a></li>
<li><a href="host:8080/geoserver/rest/security/roles/about/manifest">about/manifest</a></li>
<li><a href="host:8080/geoserver/rest/security/roles/about/version">about/version</a></li>
<li><a href="host:8080/geoserver/rest/security/roles/about/status">about/status</a></li>
<li><a href="host:8080/geoserver/rest/security/roles/settings">settings</a></li>
<li><a href="host:8080/geoserver/rest/security/roles/settings/contact">settings/contact</a></li>
<li><a href="host:8080/geoserver/rest/security/roles/services/wms/settings">services/wms/settings</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried sending an email to the email listed on the api documentation page but received a "returned to sender".

We are using geoserver 2.11.1

Comment: did you join the user's list before you sent it email?